# How to add/update iteration of a gitlab issue using API?

Tags: gitlab

Tried

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <MY_TOKEN>" \
--data '{"iteration_id": 123}' \
"https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/issues/<ISSUE_ID>"
```

Error: assignee_id, assignee_ids, confidential, created_at, description, discussion_locked, due_date, labels, add_labels, remove_labels, milestone_id, state_event, title, issue_type, weight, epic_id, epic_iid are missing, at least one parameter must be provided

So, I tried adding one of those mandatory fields to the request body, but then only that field got updated but not the iteration_id